# Fetch an xlsx from a daily mailer that I recieve and import it to a fixed googlesheet

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function getRawData() {
    // This gets the threads
    var threads = GmailApp.search('from:(it@xyz.org) ((has:attachment OR has:drive) cod pendency report)');
    var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0]; // returns the first message from the first thread
    var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0]; // returns the first attachment
    var xlsxBlob = attachment; // This is a blob, yes.
    
    var convertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},xlsxBlob).id;
    Logger.log('successfully converted')
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0];
    Logger.log('temp file opened')
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // gets values from first tab
    
  
    var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('designated_target_sheet_id').getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length);
    dataSheet.clear()
    dataRange.setValues(data);
    
    // Moved this line to the end because you were deleting it before using the data inside it.
    // Changed to trash instead of remove.
    Drive.Files.trash(convertedSpreadsheetId); // Remove the converted file.
 }
```

I used this code that I got on stackoverflow, but maybe the file  is big or I really don't know what the reason might be I have tried the following and none of them worked

1. Converting into csv and then importing
2. Without using Drive API
3. Suspecting that the file might be too large I tried reattempting
   import multiple times after fixed brakes.

Error
*Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 1lWeTw7MuEOuhD5KedL2J3r5xeY-hZIgl.
getRawData  @ c2.gs:10*

It is unable to access the imported file but I checked sheets, the temporary file is getting created. I have been stuck for a long time any help is appreciated. I am aware that there is a very similar question but I am unable to add my doubt there.
Maybe the source of the problem is that the attachment file is of mimetype octet-stream

Comment: I would like to be clear about what you’d like to do. On a daily basis, you receive an email that contains an Excel file, and you’d like to have the contents of it compiled into a single Google Sheet. Would that be correct?

Comment: The email attachement is an updated version of the same dataset sent everyday I want to take the latest one to be stored in a designated gsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve this problem.

```
function getRawData() {
    // This gets the threads
    var threads = GmailApp.search('from:(it@xyz.org) ((has:attachment OR has:drive) cod pendency report)');
    var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0]; // returns the first message from the first thread
    var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0]; // returns the first attachment
    attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();
    var xlsxBlob = attachment; // This is a blob, yes.
    
    var convertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS},xlsxBlob).id;
    Logger.log('successfully converted')
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0];
    Logger.log('temp file opened')
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // gets values from first tab
    
  
    var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('target_spreadsheet_id').getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length);
    dataSheet.clear()
    dataRange.setValues(data);
    
    // Moved this line to the end because you were deleting it before using the data inside it.
    // Changed to trash instead of remove.
    Drive.Files.trash(convertedSpreadsheetId); // Remove the converted file.
 }
```